の after て-form in 期待してのものだった
I'm wondering about this sentence from Spy x Family, episode 7 (around 50 seconds in).
The main character is thinking about how to get closer to his target, Desmond, and is mulling over a recent setback in the process.

そこで代案として用意した
プランＢ“ナカヨシ作戦”
デズモンドの息子
ダミアンとの間に—
交友関係を築いてもらい—
あわよくば親同士でも親交をと
期待してのものだったが…
入学初日に その彼を殴り
雷(トニト)１つ 仲は最悪

(The bolded part is pronounced with a short pause after と)
Although I can understand what's being said, I'm used to の coming after a noun or a verb in plain form or past tense, so I'm not sure how it works grammatically here. Are expressions like ものだ a special case?
Also, I'm not sure why it's phrased this way to begin with. Would 期待したものだった be ungrammatical or have a different meaning?

"It (=作戦) was something based on the expectation that ～". See this link for similar questions: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/24709
